# undefined variable in codeigniter model

Tags: php, codeigniter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: “Notice: Undefined variable”  and “Notice: Undefined index”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Im trying to get my database query to work within my model for codeignuter but whenever i try to load the page it says

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: data

Filename: models/model_get.php

Line Number: 21

```
    function getLinks(){
        $q = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM links ORDER BY link_name ASC");
        if($q->num_rows() > 0){
            foreach($q->result() as $row){
                $data[] = $row;
            }
        }
        return $data;   (this is line 21)
    }
}
```

I also have another query that's in the same model with the data variable and it works just fine, i have also tired changing the variable name but that did not work either. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

It's trying to return $data right there on :21 but if there were no rows returned from the query, $data is not yet defined.

```
$data = array();
```

should be the first line of this function.

Answer (score 2):

You should define `$data` before the `if` conditional - if $q->num_rows == 0 then $data will be undefined.

It's as simple as `$data = array();` before the conditional.